# Change CSS value dynamically with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div:

```
<div class="badger-left"></div>
```

This CSS:

```
/* Change style dynamically according to the bg-color attribute added to the div from jQuery */
.badger-change:after {
    background-color: attr(bg-color);
}
```

This jQuery to add an attribute and a class:

```
$('.badger-left').addClass('badger-change').attr('bg-color','red');
```

Since jQuery can't do `:after` like in CSS, I thought of this way, but it's failing. What should I try?

Thanks

Edit: The color would change dynamically from jQuery, it won't always be red.

Comment: http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/qxFIC/ :) is that fine ?

Comment: I like the answers here, it shows some different schools of thought for tackling this problem and I know that you may not be able to implement SASS into your project, but I'm just wondering if this would be made a lot easier if you were using SASS to create the css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you can't pass it in to a color value because it will be interpreted as a string instead of a reference. You can pass in the `content` value to prove this point. On that note, you'll need to give your `:after` some layout, either with content or with some display or dimensions.

Here is a hacky workaround. I would personally refactor this to not use the pseudo style, but this will work with your current implementation:

```
function addStyle(color) {
    $('<style>.badger-left:after { background-color: ' + color + ';</style>').appendTo('head');
}

// example addStyle('red');
```

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3qK2G/

Answer (score 2):

what you can do is to set background-color in `.badger-change` and have `.badger-change:after` **inherit** this value.

In `.badger-change` you need to set a `background-color` and **hide it** width a gradient over it.

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/wtnxa/)** *(hover the div to see it in action)*

---

**[DEMO 2](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/qxFIC/)** only change `background-color` without switching classes.

---

You can think of other method with inherit , like a background image of 1 pixel set hundreds of pixel away from screen in parent container and setted as `repeat` in pseudo-element.

Answer (score 2):

How about just changing the class of .badger-left? So do something like this:

```
$('.badger-left').addClass('badger-red')
$('.badger-left').addClass('badger-blue')
```

with css like this:

```
.badger-red:after {
    background-color: red;
}

.badger-blue:after {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I didn't specify it -- the color will change dynamically from jQuery, and there can be many different colors. If I can't get the color form the attr 'bg-color', I guess I can just add multiple cs classes.

Comment: @DanyP Check my example , instead switching class , just switch bg-color http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/wtnxa/ or without classes , just bg http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/qxFIC/

Answer (score 1):

Establishing a color in your CSS prior to it being added would do the trick. Then changing that classes color later would change the `badger-left` with the new class `badger-change`

## CSS

```
/* Change style dynamically according to the bg-color attribute added to the div from jQuery */
.badger-change {
    background-color: red;
}
```

## jQuery

```
$('.badger-left').addClass('badger-change'); // As soon as we're loaded add badger-change class

$('#button').click(function(){ // When example button is clicked

    $('.badger-change').css('backgroundColor', 'blue'); // change badger-change background to blue

});
```

Here we are using a button for an example of changing the color.

## HTML

```
<div class="badger-left">Hello World</div>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Change it" />
```

Some example content for `badger-left` for example.

When the page loads `badger-left` is given the new class `badger-change` with the BG being red. Then the button fires the jQuery to change that classes BG color to blue.

## [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/WASasquatch/d38cn/)