# Jquery data attribute change and affect CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a data attribute in my css however when I change it via jquery it's not changing on screen on in the dom.

```js
$('#new-1').data('count', 5);
```

```css
.fa-stack[data-count]:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: -20%;
  top: -20%;
  content: attr(data-count);
  font-size: 90%;
  padding: .4em;
  border-radius: 999px;
  line-height: .75em;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="new-1" class="fa-stack fa has-badge" data-count="0">
<i class="fa fa-user-circle fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change CSS value dynamically with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23162621/change-css-value-dynamically-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#new-1').attr('data-count', 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check JQuery's documentation on this link

https://api.jquery.com/data/

it clearly states

> Using the data() method to update data does not affect attributes in the DOM. To set a data-* attribute value, use attr.

Hence you should use the `.attr("key", value);` function.

The code would be

```
$('#new-1').attr('data-count', 5);
```